# Task "jshint" not found

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have only just started to learn how to program using Steven Foote's book 'Learning to program' and I have hit a wall and I am looking for some help please.

When I run; grunt jshint I get the following;

```
Daniels-Air:projects danielclifford$ sudo grunt jshint
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
Warning: Task "jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

my gruntfile.js looks as follows;

```
module.exports = funtion (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
            release: {
                src: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js'],
                dest: 'release/main.js'
            }
        },
        copy: {
            release: {
                src: 'manifest.json',
                dest: 'release/manifest.json'
            }
        },
        jshint: {
            files: ['js/vales.js', 'js/prompt.js']
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'copy']);
    };
```

I've probably just made a stupid mistake but I can't find it and the other two posts with similar issues haven't helped me either so any help someone can give me would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the "grunt-contrib-jshint' npm module installed in our directory?. If not install it using 'npm-install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev'

Comment: Hi David, yes the jshint grunt plugin is installed

Comment: Can you please paste the contents of your `package.json` file here?

Comment: A stupid mistake's range is infinite. Please read this article http://www.codereadability.com/jshint-with-grunt/ to make sure you're setting up everything correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 1 of the Gruntfile.js should be `module.exports = function(grunt) {` rather than `module.exports = funtion(grunt) {`

Not seeing the function declaration can throw the `Syntax Error: Unexpected token` line that you are receiving when you try and run the task.

Comment: Knew it would be something stupid, I wrote the code twice as well and still ended up with this error haha. Thanks!

Comment: Not stupid! You'll get an intuition for those kinds of errors as you code more! Good luck!